# Convert Date format C#

Tags: c#, api, date

I am working with an API that requires a certain type of Date format. The date example I am being provided is 10/1/2020 and it converts to 1601528400000. I have never used this type of date before and completely puzzled on what it could be. Does anyone know what type of date format this is?

Example of the URL: https://www.test.org/exports?s_id=-100&g_id=-100&c_id=-100&start_date=1601528400000&end_date=1602478800000

Comment: That's a unix time stamp. https://www.unixtimestamp.com/

Comment: There is [DateTime constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.-ctor?#System_DateTime__ctor_System_Int64_) which accept long.

Comment: There's [DateTimeOffset.ToUnixTimeSeconds Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset.tounixtimeseconds?view=netcore-3.1) and [DateTimeOffset.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset.tounixtimemilliseconds?view=netcore-3.1)

Comment: @Sinatr Doesn't look like ticks, though. Unix Timestamp seems reasonable.

Answer (score -2):

https://currentmillis.com/

DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds()

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it